# remove a specific area from url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a URL such as `http://myurleg.com/ar/Message.html` and I want to replace `ar` with `en` in it, after clicking on it.

It means that if my url is: `http://myurleg.com/ar/Message.html`

After click it should become: `http://myurleg.com/en/Message.html`

I just tried

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#lng_flip').click(function () {

            var url = window.location.href.split('/')[0];
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user string `replace` :

```js
var str = "http://myurleg.com/ar/Message.html";
document.write(str);
var res = str.replace("/ar/", "/fr/");
document.write('<br /> Result : ' + res );
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ar` in **[`split('/')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** array with `en` and join it again using **[`join('/')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**

```js
var url ='http://myurleg.com/ar/Message.html'.split('/');
url[3]='en';
url=url.join('/');

document.write(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var current = location.pathname.substring(1, 3);
var flipped = current == 'en' ? 'ar' : 'en';
location.pathname = '/' + flipped + location.pathname.substring(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

A general solution, supporting any two-letter language code at the beginning of the path, would be:

```
location.href = location.href.replace(/(\/\/.*?\/)\w{2}(.*)/, '$1en$2');
```

Though sometimes it makes more sense to only manipulate `location.pathname`:

```
location.pathname = location.pathname.replace(/\/\w{2}(.*)/, '/en$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var str = 'http://myurleg.com/ar/Message.html'; 
var txt = str.replace(/ar/i,"en");
```

Or in your case

```
var url = window.location.href;
window.location.href = url.replace(/ar/i,"en");
```